# Is port 5432 open for postgres?

Tags: networking, firewall, postgresql

Here is the output of the `netstat` command on ubuntu 14.04 server:

```
admin@ibm-testbox:~$ netstat -tulnp | grep 5432
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

It seems that the port 5432 is listening to tcp traffic on loopback. The server `ibm-testbox` is behind a firewall and port forwarding is used to route the public traffic to the server. But we still can not make connection to the postgres server:

```
PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
```

Is the port 5432 open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the listening address.  As you can see it is only listening on that port via the localhost IP (`127.0.0.1:5432`).

The port is not open for external connections, which is the default setup and the most secure for most cases.